# Do I have to re-cite sources in the conclusion that I already cited in the main part of my masters thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, economics

I am currently writing the conclusion of my master's thesis. In the main part I have mostly explained an economic model and tried to make it more understandable. If I now summarize the findings in the conclusion, that is trivially the findings that the author of the model has already made. Do I have to quote the author again in the conclusion or is it sufficient to state the source in the main part?

Answer (score 1):

You get the best advice from your advisor, but I think it depends on how you write. You have to be clear about the source of things, but not everything requires a formal citation. If you quote something again, you probably need to be more formal, but if you paraphrase something you quoted and cited earlier you might do with something like "As Smith and Quine, quoted earlier, have shown, mumble grumble tumble..."

Re-read what you write and assure yourself that ideas have the proper attribution. Avoid plagiarism and make the writing clear, especially the source of ideas.